# Weird behaviour of _GET variables

Tags: php, variables, get

Actually this is my code:

```
echo "<pre>";
// get current vars
$p1 = isset($_GET['p1']) ? trim($_GET['p1']) : false;
$p2 = isset($_GET['p2']) ? trim($_GET['p2']) : false;
$p3 = isset($_GET['p3']) ? trim($_GET['p3']) : false;
$f1 = isset($_GET['f1']) ? trim($_GET['f1']) : false;
$f2 = isset($_GET['f2']) ? trim($_GET['f2']) : false;
$f3 = isset($_GET['f3']) ? trim($_GET['f3']) : false;
//Debug
echo "P1 from _GET: ".var_dump($p1);
echo "P2 from _GET: ".var_dump($p2);
echo "P3 from _GET: ".var_dump($p3);
echo "F1 from _GET: ".var_dump($f1);
echo "F2 from _GET: ".var_dump($f2);
echo "F3 from _GET: ".var_dump($f3);
```

When I went to `http://localhost/test/index.php?p2=foo&f3=bar`, I was expecting this result:

```
P1 from _GET: bool(false)
P2 from _GET: string(3) "foo"
P3 from _GET: bool(false)
F1 from _GET: bool(false)
F2 from _GET: bool(false)
F3 from _GET: string(3) "bar"
```

However, this is what I get:

```
P1 from _GET: string(3) "foo"
P2 from _GET: bool(false)
P3 from _GET: bool(false)
F1 from _GET: bool(false)
F2 from _GET: string(3) "bar"
F3 from _GET: bool(false)
```

Can you explain why?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try `var_export($p1, true)` instead of `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var_dump` is outputting before your `echo` statement actually executes.

```
echo "P1 from _GET: ".var_dump($p1);
```

should become:

```
echo "P1 from _GET: ";
var_dump($p1);
```

As a side note, when this gets executed, you *actually* (tested it myself) get the following, which should make it more obvious what's going on:

```
bool(false)
P1 from _GET: string(3) "foo"
P2 from _GET: bool(false)
P3 from _GET: bool(false)
F1 from _GET: string(3) "bar"
F2 from _GET: bool(false)
F3 from _GET:
```

Comment: +1 hehe, you posted same answer I was going to post few seconds before me